# What are Reptile's Bread and Butter combos in MK 9?

Tags: mortal-kombat-9

In the new Mortal Kombat game, what are some of the standard combos and mix ups for Reptile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Shoryuken](http://wiki.shoryuken.com/Mortal_Kombat_9/Reptile) finally posted Reptile's bread and butter combos. Here is the current list:

[image]